# Parallel transport on simplicial manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, simplicial-stuff

Do you know some reference about the notion of parallel transport for simplicial manifolds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining parallel transport is equivalent to defining a connection. Connections on simplicial manifolds are discussed in chapter 6 of Dupont's book "Curvature and characteristic classes": http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0065364